# Better way to store cookie for commandline application

Tags: c++, boost

I want to store cookie for my commandline application, for now I am using a file base approach where in I am using a file to store the data returned by server for future use in my command line application and encrypt the file.

The code goes like this

```
if ((sHeader.find("Session_ID")) != std::string::npos)
   {
     int iFound1 = sHeader.find("{");
     int iFound2 = sHeader.find("}", iFound1);
     int iLen = iFound2 - iFound1 - 1;

     std::string sessionID = sHeader.substr((iFound1 + 1), iLen);
     if (!sessionIdSet)
     {
       std::ofstream outputFile;
       outputFile.open("session.txt");
       if (outputFile.is_open())
       {
         outputFile << "Session_ID = " << sessionID << "\n" ;
         outputFile << "IP = " << cli.getIP() << "\n";
         outputFile.close();
         sessionIdSet = true;
       }
    }
  }
```

What can be a better approach to do it,, one i found is using %appdata% but i need some mechanism that is independent of underlying platform.

Comment: When it comes to files and paths, there is no real platform independent way. You have to use e.g. conditional compilation to select the path where you store the file.

Comment: Application would be used on windows and linux platform, so on the basis of these two can i have some common approach without the conditional compilation ?

Comment: Unless you're happy to save the file in the current directory only, or in a relative path from the current directory then you need conditional compilation. And remember that current directory might not always be what you expect it to be. Absolute paths are the best way, and those will be different for Linux and Windows.

Comment: That means , conditional compilation is the only way to do it ? @Someprogrammerdude if not then can you suggest any other approach ?

Comment: 1.) What is "better"? 2.) Not all systems on which you can compile C++ code actually offer a filesystem with directories for application-specific data, so you also need to think about which kind of systems you want to support. 3.) Boost.Filesystem can greatly aid you in achieving compatibility with a wide range of systems.

Comment: @ChristianHackl you didn't get my question, can i store some data in system variable (Linux and Windows ) both so that my command line application can use it ?

Comment: @DevMac: If you are asking about system variables, then you did not say so in your question. Your question only talks about files and the Windows %appdata% directory, and a "better" solution without specifying how it should be "better".

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'll make an edit in the question to be more specific and clear, have you got any way to store the sessionID to maintain the session ?